# ¿Cómo puedo definir credenciales estáticas para un proyecto en Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Buen día,
Necesito ingresar determinadas credenciales a una prueba automatizada, dado que en el script no hay ingreso de credenciales por ser una ventana de windows.
Quiero preguntar si alguien sabe como hacer para que cuando yo ejecute mi clase JAVA testcase ella inicie la ejecución con ese "nombre de usuario" y "contraseña" ya escrito...

PdT: No sé si puede configurar dentro de la clase dando clic derecho en propiedades o en alguna parte, como ejemplo, yo usaba RANOREX y a ese programa le ingresaba las credenciales y el no tenía en cuenta la ventana de login para la prueba automatizada porque ya sabía que iba a insertar las credenciales, quiero hacer algo similar en Eclipse...

Les dejo mi codigo si puede ser de ayuda:

```
 package Modulos;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    public class Normatividad {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before


      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://srvd-sp1:45002/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

      @Test
      public void testNormatividad() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx");
      //  Select UsuarioWindows = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ClaimsLogonSelector']")));
      //    UsuarioWindows.selectByValue("Windows");    
// EN TEORIA ACA DEBERIA IR EL CODIGO PARA EL CASO DE PRUEBA CON LOGIN  PERO QUIERO HACERLO CONFIGURANDO ES LA CLASE (NO SE SI SE PUEDA)
        driver.findElement(By.id("viewlist69c42153-dcc4-4897-8c14-a3dbcf2f280a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='idHomePageNewItem']/span[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField")).sendKeys("Norma Selenium IDE");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Sector_cf99eb7b-0dfd-40ad-ad32-9ba27a3fedde_$DropDownChoice")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Sector_cf99eb7b-0dfd-40ad-ad32-9ba27a3fedde_$DropDownChoice"))).selectByVisibleText("Gas");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("TipoDeNorma_fcec88c5-96c6-4096-b3f0-753b15522dd1_$DropDownChoice"))).selectByVisibleText("Decreto");
        driver.findElement(By.id("NumeroDeLaNorma_7e332ac2-55cb-4ea2-9c48-b30bed65ae62_$NumberField")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("NumeroDeLaNorma_7e332ac2-55cb-4ea2-9c48-b30bed65ae62_$NumberField")).sendKeys("877765");
        driver.findElement(By.id("FechaDeLaNorma_b2916758-64de-488d-9b1b-478209e7a7c7_$DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerImage")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DatePickerDiv > div.ms-datepickerouter > div.ms-quickLaunch > div.ms-picker-header > table.ms-picker-table > tbody > tr > td > a.ms-pagearrow-left > img.ms-pagearrow-left-icon")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("20170111")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("DescripcionDeLaNorma_c0f1e376-2baa-4425-8b69-483f1777ad1d_$TextField_inplacerte")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("DescripcionDeLaNorma_c0f1e376-2baa-4425-8b69-483f1777ad1d_$TextField_inplacerte")).sendKeys("Prueba automatizada con Selenium IDE");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='Ribbon.ListForm.Edit-title']/a/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile-Large']/span[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("onetidIOFile")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("onetidIOFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\rtalero\\Desktop\\tst-cloud.png");
        driver.findElement(By.id("attachOKbutton")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl48_g_83603d0e_fb89_4c30_a560_d43b3c5ffbfd_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"SGC\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Normatividad')])[2]")).click();
      }

      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
      }

      private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(by);
          return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
          driver.switchTo().alert();
          return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String alertText = alert.getText();
          if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
          } else {
            alert.dismiss();
          }
          return alertText;
        } finally {
          acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: La credenciales son para conectar a http://srvd-sp1:45002/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?

Comment: No, esa URL me permite ir a una lista de sharepoint dónde en teoría puedo crear un elemento, pero cuando ejecuto el caso de prueba en eclipse, me manda a esa URL, pero al agregar un elemento automáticamente me manda a la ventana de login, esto es creo porque al arrancar la ejecución me abre es un navegador anónimo...

Answer (score 0):

Debes dar clic derecho en cualquier parte del código de tu prueba e ir a la seccion de Run As > Run configurations...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente ventana agrega las variables que quieras en la seccion de  VM arguments anteponiendo "-D" y cada variable separa por un espacio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho esto podrás acceder a los valores de cada variable en cualquier parte de los métodos de la siguiente manera:

```
String usuario = System.getProperty("usuario");
String contrasenia = System.getProperty("contrasenia");
```